# How do you send json instance requests to an uploaded model on GCP to call predict?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deployment

I am building an AI prediction model, and built it with inputs that are of type ndarray. After uploading it to Google Cloud Models (not using Vertex), I don't seem to be able to make a request using the predict function because the types are not JSON Serializable.

I keep getting errors such as ndarray is not json serializable. Converting it to a list to make it JSON serializable gives me Prediction failed: unknown error.

I tried changing the input for the Model to a data type that is JSON serializable but couldn't find anything to work with. Using a dict for input only works with converting the DataFrame to a dict.